# View is not getting updated sometimes after $http call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, asynchronous

I know this question is asked many times, but none of the solution is working for me.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $timeout, $http) {

      $scope.eventData = {
        heading: "",
        description: ""
      };

      $http.get("/GetEvents")
        .then(function (response) {

          $scope.eventData.heading = response.data.heading;
          $scope.eventData.description = response.data.description;

          console.log($scope.eventData);
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <h3>{{eventData.heading}}</h3>
  <p>{{eventData.description}</p>
</div>
```

Sometimes when I refresh the page, It does not show the values description and heading. Maybe it is empty("") string. This is random, sometimes values are visible and sometimes not.
It looks very simple. I am not able to find the mistake. I do not know why this random behaviour. However console prints the correct values always.

Note* I am including jQuery also.

Comment: The code looks correct. When you refresh the page, you will expect to see no values, until the AJAX request completes. Does your console log show an error, or does it show the request being completed?

Comment: @xbonez Console does not show any error. It always shows the presence of values

Comment: you haven't included a *complete* example here.  specifically, you aren't showing where the `ng-app` or `ng-controller` are in your HTML, and if you are using any other angular directives like `ng-if`, `ng-include`, `ng-repeat`, etc. that might be creating additional scopes which can potentially hide data properties, causing the problem you are describing.

Comment: You can *force* the http call. Put the call inside a function and add the ng-init="myFunction()" where you define and load the controller

Answer (score 0):

You load the data in **asynchronous** way which means that the HTML loads first (all the DOM elements are shown) and when you get the response from the server, then the object `$scope.eventData` gets values.

I believe the best way to handle this is by showing a **loader png**.
Just show the loader.png before calling the `$http.get("/GetEvents")` and hide it inside the `.then()`.

### Another trick:

use `ng-if` directive to show a 'loading' text inside your DOM elements until you get the response from the server, like so:

```
<div>
  <h3 ng-if="eventData.heading != ''">{{eventData.heading}}</h3>
  <h3 ng-if="eventData.heading == ''">Loading..</h3>

  <p ng-if="eventData.description !=''">{{eventData.description}</p>
  <p ng-if="eventData.description ==''">Loading..</p>
</div>
```

Hope helps, good luck.